# Feeling of missing someone

Tags: single-word-requests

What’s that word that describes the feeling when something you see/hear/smell reminds you of someone? For example if you go to the park and you see the place where you had a first kiss with someone and that place makes you miss that person?
It isn’t something that you do voluntarily, it’s more like a thing that pops out in your head and you can’t get it out.
(I remember my English teacher talking about it I just don’t know what it is)

“I went to the park today and that bench triggered my ____”

Comment: ... The duplicate expands on the title: 'Is there a noun that precisely describes the emotion of missing someone ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"reminiscence" comes close perhaps.

Answer (score 5):

"[nostalgia](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/nostalgia)" may be the word you want:

> *nostalgia*: a feeling that a time in the past was good, or the activity of remembering a good time in the past and wishing that things had not changed

Comment: more like _añorar_, no? I do not think there is a good word in English for this.

Comment: @Cascabel The word in Spanish would be *añoranza: acción de añorar, nostalgia.*